# How to split a zip list in python?

Tags: python, sqlite

I need to split this list from sqlite3

`[(107, u'Ella', u'Fitzgerald'), (108, u'Louis', u'Armstrong'), (109, u'Miles', u'Davis'), (110, u'Benny', u'Goodman')]`

into

```
107, 'Ella', 'Fitzgerald'
108, 'Louis', 'Armstrong'
109, 'Miles', 'Davis'
110, 'Benny', 'Goodman'
```

How to get this?

Thanks.

Comment: It is not clear what you want to get. Are you trying to get that as output in the console? Store it in a variable?

Comment: Splitting this into several lists would be pretty useless, as you can access them with `yourlist[0]`, `yourlist[1]`, etc.?

Comment: Yes, I need that will be store in variable, so i will combine with texttable to get pretty printing as an output in text file. Like this one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
data = [(107, u'Ella', u'Fitzgerald'), (108, u'Louis', u'Armstrong'), (109, u'Miles', u'Davis'), (110, u'Benny', u'Goodman')]

for record in data:
    print '{0:}, {1:}, {2:}'.format(*record)

# or in case you want to get a dictionary

d = dict([(x[0], ', '.join(x[1:])) for x in a])# sure that you can skip merging name and surname here(just replace join with x[1:])
for k, v in d.iteritems():
    print '%s, %s' % (k, v)

>>>107 Ella, Fitzgerald
>>>108 Louis, Armstrong
>>>109 Miles, Davis
>>>110 Benny, Goodman
```

Comment: thank you, this is very helpful. Also i need the first comma separated.`code`>>>107, Ella, Fitzgerald
>>>108, Louis, Armstrong
>>>109, Miles, Davis
>>>110, Benny, Goodman`code`

Comment: @kuslanhe - you are welcome and remember if you like anybodies answer vote it))) or down-vote otherwise(but then leave comment why)

Answer (score 0):

This way you separate your tuple into 3 different variables:

```
for tuples in sqlite_list:
    id, name, last_name = tuples
.... #Do what you need
```

Comment: sorry i am newbie in python, can you give me example. thanks.

Comment: You can just do `for id, name, last_name in sqlite_list:` directly.